# Data analysis basics using pandas and numpy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook, nan

I am not able to replace not a number value(NaN) using the command `df.replace('?', np.NaN)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming df is the original DataFrame
df = df.replace('?', np.NaN)  
# Replace '?' with NaN and assign the result back to df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question it sounds like you want to replace `np.NaN` with `'?'`, but in the code I think you are requesting the reverse. I am not sure which way round you need the replacement. If you want to remove the `np.NaN` and have `'?'` instead, then this should work:

```py
df = df.replace({np.NaN: '?'})
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Hope you are doing well!

If I understood your question correctly then the solution should be like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example of the DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, "?"], "B": [4, "?", 5]})

# replace ? with pd.NA / np.nan / None
df = df.replace("?", pd.NA)

print(df)
#      A     B
#0     1     4
#1     2  <NA>
#2  <NA>     5
```

You can also use `np.nan` instead of `pd.NA` or standard Python's `None`. But my personal suggestion is `pd.NA` if you will operate with DataFrames only later.

Comment: Yes, that should normally work, but the OP clearly does not have a `df` that looks like this one, because if s/he did, `df = df.replace('?', np.NaN)` would (or: should) simply work.